# Disable 2FA on Microsof365

Tags: office-365, multi-factor-auth, imap

My organisation uses Microsoft365. In particular, we use outlook online for emails. Microsoft switched off basic authentication from 1st October 2022, although there was an extension given to some organisations, including mine, up to 25th January 2023.

Do you guys know if my organisation is able to switch off 2FA on my account for IMAP access, or is this not possible? App passwords have been turned off when Microsoft deprecated basic auth.

I'm having a hard time finding a definite answer on the internet...

Thanks!